# Два хидера в Listview

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня есть `ListView` с хидером.Если пользователь выбрал только "В одну сторону" то выводиться этот `ListView` с одним хидером, а если выбрал туда и обратно, то должен появиться второй `Listview` тоже с хидером.

Вопрос: как правильно будет, создать два `ListView` или в тот же `ListView` добавить в конец один хидер и айтемы низ него? Если первый, то как со скроллом быть, так как у обоих скроллы разные будут. А если второй как реализовать?

Если будут типа где ошибка, как ты старался вопросы. Я стараюсь везде перерыл, но именно по моему вопросу ответа не нашел. У меня просто каша в голове и даже логика не работает.

Comment: Вам нужен  один ListView, А хедер сделайте просто частью элемента списка. Просто он для многих элементов будет скрываться. Или просто в списке может быть два разных типа элемента.

Comment: Как сделать частью элемента?

Comment: http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android